# Layout for Android App

Tags: android

I googled this think very much time , and I get nothing. I want to know if there is a way to create layouts for android apps in the illustrator , and be able to use them like you made in an XML file. I know this is a dumb question , but I'm newbie in android apps , and I'm very curios , because I want to make a very custom grid view wich I can't make it like in old way ,or even through code.. or I think I can do it with math code , but it will be very painful !! Thank you every one for interest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "in the illustrator" ? Do you mean Adobe Illustrator, or the "Design" tab in the IDE layout editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some Toolkits for Android you can find them under:

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

But as far as I know it is not possible to create an xml layout for android under adobe illustrator. However a grid layout is a grid. If you want something special you have to use a relative layout. You could also use canvas or drawables, it depends of what you want.

First of all you have to do it programmatically, under the following link is a tutorial of how you can build up an hexgrid.

https://github.com/riotopsys/Hexgrid

If you're done with it you can add a circle button to every corner. Just use a drawable button for this.

Comment: I want an hexagon grid with 19 hexagon and in every corner of the hexagon to be an circle grid wich I can click at , and change his aspect . And also in every hex Grig I want an circle grid... How do you think I  can accomplish that ?

Comment: Added tutorial in answer

Comment: ok man , thank you for your effort !! this is what I was looking for